# Extended Kalman filter for vehicle tracking

Tags: filtering, kalman-filter

I have read somewhere that movement of a vehicle in cities is non-linear. It accelerates or de-accelerates frequently.

Can I use Extended Kalman filter for vehicle tracking moving on a road?

I am not able to understand the difference between KF and EKF.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a KF and EKF is in the **model** that is used, i.e. the equations used for propagation of the state (transition) and measurement update. If the model is linear, you can use a KF, EKF's are used for non-linear models.

For your case, the movement may not be linear, you can still create a linear state transition model: 
Assume a vehicle with 1 dimensional motion. You could model this using a state [x,v,a] (position, speed, acceleration). 
The state transition can be modeled as:

[image: eq1]

which is a linear model.